# ST_Within from centroid of geometry

Tags: spatialite, spatial-query

I am looking at doing a spatial query where I can find when the center of one feature falls within another. For example, when the center (centroid) of a building falls within a grid tile. I know I can do this if I create a centroid of the building polygon, but I would like to do this on the polygon layer. Is there a way to do this with ST_Within, or another function?

Thanks...

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you might try `ST_Within(ST_Centroid(building_geom), other_geom)`

If that's not what you're asking, could you clarify what you mean by "I would like to do this on the polygon layer", as in, what the "do this" is referring to?